# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath Patient.nachname not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Patient id=1>'

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Why I am getting a NSInvalidArgumentException?

My table view controller code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(MRMedSafeAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest  *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest  alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription  *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                entityForName:@"Patient" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor  *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"Patient.nachname" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor  *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"Patient.vorname" ascending:YES];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray  arrayWithObjects:sort1, sort2, nil]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:cdh.context
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

My Patient.h:

```
@interface Patient : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * geburtsdatum;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nachname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * vorname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * weiblich;
@end
```

My Patient.m:

```
#import "Patient.h"
@implementation Patient
@dynamic geburtsdatum;
@dynamic nachname;
@dynamic vorname;
@dynamic weiblich;
@end
```

Patient.h and Patient.h generated by XCode 5 out of the Model.xcdatamodeld file.

Why I am getting an exception?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath Patient.nachname not found in entity '

Patient is the only class, there are no other model classes and no relationships in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "nachname" instead of "Patient.nachname" in

```
NSSortDescriptor  *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                        initWithKey:@"Patient.nachname" ascending:YES];
```

I.e. it should read

```
NSSortDescriptor  *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                        initWithKey:@"nachname" ascending:YES];
```

Likewise for the next sort descriptor and "vorname".